# Call notifyItemChanged(int position) or equivalent from RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

My `RecyclerView` items contains views that have 4 TextViews. I "collapse" and "expand" each view item by setting 2 TextViews' View.visibility to `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBILITY` respectively by implementing `onClick(View view)`. I know I must call `notifyItemChanged(int position)` function of my `RecyclerView` adapter after a collapse/expand but the problem is that `position` of view item cannot be (normally) accessed from its `ViewHolder`.

As a workaround, I have created a 5th `TextView` in a view item to hold the `position` of the item. I access this textview from the view passed to `onClick()` and thus get the position of the item that I use to call `notifyItemChanged(position)` and update the screen.

My solution works but I am looking for a cleaner solution. Using a view to save item position is definitely not good idea

Here's the important parts of my code:

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<Notification> notifications;
    // Notification is my custom class (POJO)
    public NotificationAdapter(Context context, List<Notification> notificationList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.notifications = notificationList;
    }
    public class NotificationHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        View view;
        //The 4 TextViews
        TextView titleTv, descTv, timeTv,extraTv;
        //TextView added to hold position of the view item
        TextView positionJugad;
        public NotificationHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_subject_tv);
            descTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_body_tv);
            timeTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_time_tv);
            extraTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_extra_info_tv);
            positionJugad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_view_position);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.view = itemView;
        }
        public void bindNotification(Notification notification, int position){
            titleTv.setText(notification.getTitle());
            descTv.setText(notification.getDescription());
            timeTv.setText(notification.getTime();
            extraTv.setText(notification.getExtra());
            positionJugad.setText(""+position);
        }
        public void collapseView(){
            descTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            extraTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        public void expandView(){
            descTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            extraTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            //get the textview that stores position
            TextView jugad = view.findViewById(R.id.notification_view_position);
            if(descTv.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                expandView();
            }
            else collapseView();
            notifyViewToggle(Integer.parseInt(jugad.getText().toString()));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public NotificationHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.notification_item,parent,false);
        return new NotificationHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotificationHolder holder, int position) {
        Notification notification = notifications.get(position);
        holder.bindNotification(notification,position);
    }
    //To change view state from collapsed to expanded and vice versa
    public void notifyViewToggle(int position){

            notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notifications.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have to use another text view to store the position. instead, use

```
getAdapterPosition()
```

which gives you the current [adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) position.

your onClick should look like this

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if(descTv.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                expandView();
            }
            else collapseView();
            notifyViewToggle(getAdapterPosition());
        }
```

and modify notifyViewToggle to this

```
notifyViewToggle(int position)
```